# Is the difference of measurable sets $A,A'\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ also measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure (not necessarily the Lebesgue measure) and let $A,A'\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be two $\mu$-measurable sets satisfying $A\neq A'$. **Is the difference $\mathcal{A}=A-A'$ also a measurable set?** I think that the result is true for the case in which $n=1$, but I'm not sure if the result extends beyond $n>1$. I would show an attempt at reasoning about the question, but to be honest I'm quite lost (even the smallest hint will be much appreciate).

Comment: $A-A'=A\cap (A')^c$

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti **Thank you very much for your helpful hint**. Let's see if I'm understanding it correctly... Because $A'$ is measurable, so it is its complement $(A')^c$. Then, since the intersection of two measurable sets is also a measurable set, we have that $A\cap (A')^c$ is measurable, thus concluding that $\mathcal{A}$ is measurable. Am I reasoning correctly about it or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti **Thank you** for providing a hint that allowed me reason properly about my question. If you wish, you can post an answer to my question and I'll happily accept it.